# Why am I getting undefined values from reading a binary file in c?

Tags: c, arrays

I am writing a program that stores inventory (three arrays of numbers) using dynamically allocated arrays and storing the arrays in a binary file called "inventory.txt". The problem/question I have is I am getting really weird numbers in the arrays when I print them out. the program is incorrectly reading the binary file, the size of the arrays gets read into the program as the correct amount of elements are displayed and the numbers don't change through multiple iterations.   How do I read the numbers correctly so the program displays the correct numbers??

There are two programs, the first creates a binary file "inventory.txt" and continuously puts three variables part number, quantity, and price into a dynamically allocated array that increases with each entry and ends when the user enters 0 for part number(just enter one 0). The second program just reads the arrays and the array size stored in the binary file "inventory.txt" and prints "i" amount of rows with the numbers stored in them. Here are the two programs.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




//THIS IS FIRST PROGRAM THAT STORES THE ARRAY BASED ON USER INPUT
int main(){
 printf("This program stores an invetory: ");//declarations
 int i=0, holdr, k=0;
 int *pn, *q;
 float *p;


 q=malloc(sizeof(int));
 pn=malloc(sizeof(int));      //allocate space
 p=malloc(sizeof(float));





 FILE *fp;
 fp=fopen("inventory.txt","w+b");    //open file




 while(holdr!=0){
 pn=realloc(pn, (i+1) * sizeof(int));    //read data into the three arrays
 q=realloc(q, (i+1) * sizeof(int));
 p=realloc(p, (i+1) * sizeof(float));
 printf("Please enter item data (part number, quantity, price): ");
 scanf("%d,%d,%f",&pn[i],&q[i],&p[i]);
 holdr=pn[i];
 i++;
 k++;
 }




 fwrite(&i,sizeof(int),1,fp);               //write arrays to inventory.txt(binary)
 fwrite(&pn,sizeof(int),k,fp);
 fwrite(&q,sizeof(int),k,fp);
 fwrite(&p,sizeof(float),k,fp);
 printf("Thank you. Inventory stored in inventory.txt. \n"); 


 fp=fopen("inventory.txt","r+b");        //Check to see if file is correct by printing from the file inside the same program.


 if (fp == NULL){
 printf("nah");
 exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }

 for(i=0;i<k;i++){
 fread(&pn,sizeof(int),k,fp);     //THIS DISPLAYS THE ARRAYS CORRECTLY AS ENTERED
 printf("%d\t" , pn[i]);
 fread(&q,sizeof(int),k,fp);
 printf("%d\t", q[i]);
 fread(&p,sizeof(int),k,fp);
 printf("%f\n", p[i]);}

 fclose(fp);
 return 0;
}
```

And then...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//THE SECOND FILE THAT PRINTS OUT THE ARRAYS FROM THE FIRST PROGRAM
int main(){


FILE *fp = fopen("inventory.txt","r+b");  //declarations

if (fp == NULL){      //check file
printf("nah");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int i;
fread(&i,sizeof(int),1,fp); //get size of arrays from "i" in the other program, THIS PART WORKS 


int l,k;
int *pn, *q;
float *p;


q  = (int *)malloc(i * sizeof(int));  // TODO - check malloc() OK
pn = (int *)malloc(i * sizeof(int));  // TODO - check malloc() OK
p  = (float *)malloc(i * sizeof(float));  // TODO - check malloc() OK


fread( q, sizeof( int ), i, fp );   //read arrays in file into program
fread( p, sizeof( float ), i, fp );
fread( pn, sizeof( int ), i, fp );


printf("Below are the items in your inventory.\nPart#\tQuantity\tPrice\n");   
for(l=0;l<i;l++){                   //THIS DISPLAYS WEIRD ASS NUMBERS

printf("%d\t" , pn[l]);

printf("%d\t", q[l]);

printf("%f\n", p[l]);}
rewind(fp);
fclose(fp);
return 0;}
```

Comment: Should `fread(&pn,sizeof(int),k,fp);` be `fread(&pn,sizeof(int),1,fp);` ?  Other problems exist too.

Comment: Check the order in which you read in your reading program. If you write as `pn, q, p` you should read in that order too.

Comment: `fwrite(&pn,sizeof(int),k,fp)` should not have the ampersand (`&`).   Same for the corresponding `fread()` calls.     Same for the other dynamically allocated memory.     Saving pointers to a file (as distinct from what the pointers point at) and then reading in typically yields undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple issues with your program. First, for the program to run at all, you need to define `holdr` to non-zero value.

```
int i=0, holdr=1, k=0;
```

The first step in debugging file write/read issues is to inspect the file written by your program. On hexdump'ing the output file, I saw that the file contained only garbage values, so your write program itself is broken. With this info, if we look at your code, the reason why your program writes out garbage values is because of using address operator on an already pointer type in `fwrite`

```
fwrite(&i,sizeof(int),1,fp);      //this is okay, i is an int, &i is int*
fwrite(&pn,sizeof(int),k,fp);     //this is not okay, pn is int*, &pn is int**
```

Essentially you're writing the address of your array to the file instead of contents of your array. So, while reading back you'll get the addresses of your array - which would appear garbage.

Along with fixing so many other issues in your program, remove the `&` from fwrite of the arrays, then your program would write proper values and hence your reading program also can read the right values.

```
fwrite(pn,sizeof(int),k,fp);     //this is the right usage, pn is int*
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not initialize `int holdr`. So `while(holdr!=0)` is undefined behavior. There's no telling what that variable holds, so your loop may or may not even begin.

The calls to `realloc` appear immediately after you allocated memory with `malloc`, but there is no test to see if you need additional space. Usually one would write something like `if (not_enough_space) realloc(something)`. Your code (assuming it even runs past that undefined behavior noted earlier), will just allocate space for a single integer for pn and q, and space for a single float for p, voiding the need for the malloc in the first place.

You said that your results do not change... This is due to the fact that your arrays are constantly re-allocated and values are stored to them without you writing the results to the file. It just loops infinitely, asking for user input until `pn[0]` happens to become 0.

In the second source file, `int i` must be initialized before use.

There is no reason to cast the result of malloc. pointers to void are basically typeless memory addresses.